# Why is "on the season" used in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> The 5-foot-8 midfielder scored a goal and notched an assist for three total points **on** the season. ([The San Diego Union Tribune](http://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/news/sd-tm-0713-watn-gonter-20180703-story.html))

I thought the preposition **in** usually collocates with season. Why is it *on the season* here instead of *in the season*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two most likely prepositions in that context and meaning would be **for** the season and **on** the season; the reference is to the *full duration* of the (playing) season, the season *in its entirety*.

Compare:

> They had three flat tires on the drive across the country.

Comment: ...or, for the season _up to this point in time_ – if the season isn't over yet.

Comment: Yes indeed.  The portion of the season that has transpired.

Answer (score 2):

This phrase is only used with sports, meaning the total points scored during the sports season (until now).

You can't say "on the season" to refer to other kinds of seasons:

> (wrong): We've had three snowstorms on the season.
>   
>  (right): We've had three snowstorms during/in the season.
>   
>  (also right): We've had three snowstorms this season.

Comment: Simple:  this season.  Convoluted:  on the season.  Wish announcers would quit saying “on the season,” “on the night,” etc.